# Relace multiple Substrings in MySQL result

Tags: mysql, regex, preg-replace

Is there a way to replace multiple substrings in a single mysql column field?
In my result, there are fields like:

```
'&DY, &Q3'
```

In this case, DY and Q3 are match codes which I have to replace with a defined Word.

I tried to work with this regex_replace function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000)) RETURNS varchar(1000)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000); 
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1); 
 DECLARE i INT;
 SET i = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN 
  loop_label: LOOP 
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label;  
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
   END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 RETURN temp;
END
```

My SQL Query:

```
SELECT REGEX_REPLACE(fm.column,'(\&[\w]{2})*','My Word') FROM `table` fm WHERE id = '123'
```

didn't work. Maybe one problem is, that my substrings begin with "&" which is an operator in regex!?

Comment: Try using the character name instead? `[[.ampersand.]]`

Answer (score -1):

try this, but i have use MariaDB they have REGEX_REPLACE internal

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_replace/

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('&DY, &Q3','\(\&[A-Z0-9]+\),*','My Word');
```

**Result:**

```
My Word My Word
```

Comment: The question was tagged as MySQL, so a function that doesn't exist in MySQL was not so useful!

Comment: Sorry my mobile crashs